# How can I grab the correct JSON response using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: uitableview, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am making a GET request using alamofire and attempting to convert to JSON using SwiftyJSON. I can successfully make the request, but I'm unable to convert the response into a usable JSON object.

I am trying to grab data from a foursquare venue detail response, and update a UITableView (the detail page) with appropriate information about the venue. The UITableView has 3 different sections.

Here is my makeRequest code for VenueDetailViewController (UITableViewController).

```
func makeRequest() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, self.foursquareEndpointURL, parameters: [

        "client_id" : self.foursquareClientID,
        "client_secret" : self.foursquareClientSecret,
        "v" : "20140806"
        ])
        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)
            println(data)
            if data != nil {
                var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
                // response is not in the form of an array? I think... thats why data is not setting .. I think "arrayValue" below is incorrect. should be something like dictionaryValue or stringValue
                if let obj = jsonObj["response"]["venue"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                    self.responseitems = obj
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    println("Objis: \(obj)")
                }

            }
    }
}
```

When I `println("Obis: \(obj)")` I get a console output of `Objis: []` telling me that I'm grabbing the wrong data from the JSON response? Here is the url for the [Foursquare Venue Detail API request](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/51d9ade3498eeedbc8f06c0a)

Oh and `self.responseitems` is `var responseitems:[JSON] = []`

Please help! Thanks

Comment: You declare obj as an Array of Json, try to access one of the JSON types inside the array. for example: `println(“Objis: \(obj.first)”)` this will return an optional value, it will return the first item in the array if there is an item available, if there is no item available it will return nil

Comment: @milo526 did you look at the foursquare API response link I provided? Given that response and its structure, Is it even correct for me to declare obj as an Array? Or should I be declaring obj as a different SwiftyJSON type? Keep in mind self.responseitems

Comment: The foursquare Venue Detail API request is not available for non-foursquare members. I do not have such an account so was unable to see it, maybe you can upload a screenshot of the part of the API Documentation that is interesting regarding your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
let url = "Foursquare Venue Detail API request goes here"
    Alamofire .request(.GET, url) .responseJSON(options: nil) { (_, _, data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else if let data: AnyObject = data {
            let jObj = JSON(data)
            if let venue = jObj["response"]["venue"].dictionary {
                println(venue)
            }

        }
    }
```

So the main difference here is that the data is a dict, not an array.

By the way, consider reloading the table view in the main queue as this affects the UI:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData() // Update UI
}
```

Comment: This works for the `println(venue)`. I am updating a UITableView with information from the response. The UITableView has 3 cells, each with its own custom class. "VenueDetailHeaderCell" and "VenueDetailInformationCell" etc which will update based on items grabbed from the response. This is what I was trying to do with `self.responseitems = obj` in my code above, in which I would then do something like `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VenueDetailHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VenueDetailHeaderCell
            cell.headerInfo = self.responseitems[indexPath.row]`

Comment: I just created a new question regarding my comment above here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725241/how-can-i-use-swiftyjson-dictionaryvalue-as-a-usable-string-for-a-uilabel