# How can I use swiftyJSON dictionaryValue as a usable string for a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a `makeRequest()` method inside a UITableViewController with the following code:

```
    func makeRequest() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, self.foursquareEndpointURL, parameters: [
        //"VENUE_ID" : self.foursquareVenueID,
            "client_id" : self.foursquareClientID,
            "client_secret" : self.foursquareClientSecret,
            "v" : "20140806"
            ])
        .responseJSON(options: nil) { (_, _, data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else if let data: AnyObject = data {
            let jObj = JSON(data)
            if let venue = jObj["response"]["venue"].dictionaryValue as [String: JSON]? {
                self.responseitems = jObj
                println("venue is: \(venue)")
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData() // Update UI
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also keep in mind that I have a property `var responseitems:JSON = []`

`println("venue is: \(venue)")` prints a nice looking response to console, so I know that is working correctly...

I also have a custom UITableViewCell class with a `bindData()` method with the following code:

```
func bindData() {
    println("VenueDetailHeaderCell data did set")
    self.venueDetailTitleLabel.text = self.headerInfo?["name"].stringValue
    let labelData = self.headerInfo?["name"].stringValue
    println("labelData is: \(labelData)")
}
```

As you can see, I am attempting to set a UILabel's text to the ["name"].stringValue in the JSON response. However, when I `println("labelData is: \(labelData)")` I get console output of labelData is: Optional("") which is obviously empty.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to grab

[image]

What am I doing wrong here and how can I grab the name of the venue and assign my UILabel to it?

UPDATE:

I tried the following code

```
let labelData = self.headerInfo?["name"].error
    println("labelData is: \(labelData)")
```

And get a console output of: "Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 "Array[0] failure, It is not an array" UserInfo=0x7fd6d9f7dc10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Array[0] failure, It is not an array}" If that is of use to anyone. I am really confused here... Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you setting the value for `self.headerInfo` in your custom `UITableViewCell`? I'm assuming you want that set to the `venue` JSON object. However, it doesn't appear that you are ever doing that in any of your provided sample code.

Comment: @cnoon I do  `var headerInfo:JSON? {
        didSet {
            self.bindData()
        }
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `headerInfo` value is an error `JSON` object, because you're trying to access a dictionary with an integer index.

Note that `var responseitems:JSON = []` does not create an array object. SwiftyJSON has auto-assignment-constructors (I'm new to swift, so not sure what the correct swift terminology is)... see this initialiser in the SwiftyJSON.swift source code:

```
extension JSON: ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: AnyObject...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }
}
```

What this means is that when you do `var responseitems:JSON = []` you are not creating an array, you are creating a `JSON` object that is constructed with an empty array using the above `init` method. Then when you do `self.responseitems = jObj` you are re-assigning that `responseitems` variable to a `JSON` object with a dictionary in it. Therefore `self.responseitems[0]` is invalid.

Also note that with SwiftyJSON, there is no such thing as an optional `JSON` object. I notice in your comment you say that you do `var headerInfo:JSON? ...` - it's not possible to have an optional `JSON`.

```
var headerInfo: JSON = nil
```

The above is possible - this uses another auto-initialiser that initialises a valid `JSON` object that represents the JSON null value.

So, how to fix it?

When you assign `headerInfo` do it like this:

```
let headerInfo = self.responseitems["response"]["venue"]
```

And now in `bindData` you can do:

```
self.venueDetailTitleLabel.text = self.headerInfo["name"].stringValue
```

Note that all of the above assumes Swift 1.2 and SwiftyJSON >= 2.2 - also after you've understood the above and corrected the issue, you will probably want to refactor the code a bit to reflect the corrected understanding of the data-model.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. However, I'm getting no errors for `var headerInfo:JSON?` . Does this mean that it is in fact possible to have it be optional? I put the ? there as a check to prevent it crashing if it returned nil. Also, what would you recommend as far as refactoring the code to reflect the corrected understanding of the data-model? Thanks again

Comment: It's not an error or problem to make `headerInfo: JSON?` but my point is, even though it's optional, you will *never* get a nil value, always a valid JSON object. However, you can still check if `headerInfo == nil` but note that this is not doing what you think it is doing. It creates a valid JSON object initialised with nil (internally stored as NSNull) on the right-hand-side and then compares that to your `headerInfo` on the left-hand-side. Set a breakpoint and step into the code to see what happens. Re. refactoring - don't worry about it, that would just be me being picky.

Answer (score 0):

The way to parse is the next

```
element: JSONValue //Something with JSONValue
if let title = element["name"]?.string {
    cell.title.text = title
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that `var responseitems:JSON = []` So I'm already doing what you suggest with no luck.

Comment: I also do a `var headerInfo:JSON? {
        didSet {
            self.bindData()
        }
    }` in VenueDetailHeaderCell which is a UITableView class